Where to find space to share ideas and get feeddback
I study mathematics as an enthusiast, mainly of discrete math and computational geometry.
First of all I would like to thank SE, especially Mathematica and Mathematics sites
for helping me with difficult issues.
Often I see that my handmade ideas are interesting and promising.
This is also noted by scientists in private correspondence.
But professional scientists have little time.
There is almost no communication in the Wolfram Community.
A SE community is primarily for questions and answers,
not recommended to share ideas for feedback.
For publishing articles I do not have the necessary status.
Are there any resources (in the area of mathematical modeling, geometry etc)
where can I share ideas, get feedback, find enthusiasts for further research?
Would be very grateful for any advice and recommendations!

Resources in the SE network, or in general? Only the first option would make this a valid question here, I fear.

The only space available in Stack Exchange for those things is the chat.
Each site has its own chat room, and the requirement is pretty low, with 20 reputation you can chat freely.
